# How do I (C++ STL) binary_search for Abstract classes?

Tags: c++, stl, abstract, binary-search

One can use the STL binary search algorithms (binary_search, upper_bound, lower_bound) to search a vector of Base pointers for a derived object, as shown below. Since Base is abstract (protected constructor), one has to instantiate a Derived object for the search functions, which is slightly ugly.

I want to search the vector for the first Derived above a given time. Can I do this without arbitrarily picking and instantiating one of my many inherited classes?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class Base {
protected:
  Base(double t, int d) : data(d), time(t) {}
public:
  double time;
  int data;
  virtual void print() { 
    printf("Base: data = %d, time = %.1f\n",data,time); 
  }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived(double t, int d) : Base(t,d) {}
  virtual void print() { 
    printf("Derived: data=%d, time=%.1f\n",data,time);
  }
};

struct BaseTimeComp {
  bool operator()(Base* a, Base* b) { return a->time < b->time; }
};

int main()
{
  vector<Base*> v;
  for(int i=0; i<5; i++) { v.push_back(new Derived(i+0.4,i)); }

  Base* pLow = *(lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),
                             new Derived(3.5,0), //NOT "new Base(3.5,0)"
                             BaseTimeComp()));
  printf("lower bound for time=3.5:\n");
  pLow->print();
}
```

The program prints:
lower bound for time=3.5:
Derived: data=4, time=4.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The target of the comparison doesn't have to be the same type as the contents of the container, it just has to be something you can *compare* to the container:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;

    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);

    int i = *(lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 1.5));  // <<< NOTE: floating point "value"

    cout << i << endl;
}
```

Your assumption that you have to make some kind of `Base` is wrong.  You can define a `BaseKey` which is suitable for your comparisons as long as your explicit (or implied) comparison operator knows what to do.

The comment below is also wrong, as this more complex example demonstrates:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct A {
    int x;
    A(int _x) :x(_x) { }

    bool operator < (double d) { return x < d; }
};

int main()
{
    vector<A> v;

    v.push_back(A(1));
    v.push_back(A(2));
    v.push_back(A(3));

    int i = (lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 1.5))->x;

    cout << i << endl;
}
```

You can also use a comparision type explicitly (which helps with order of operations problems such as you might find with `upper_bound`):

```
class CompareADouble {
public:
    bool operator () (const double d, A& a) { return d < a.x; }
};

int main()
{
    vector<A> v;

    v.push_back(A(1));
    v.push_back(A(2));
    v.push_back(A(3));

    int i = (upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 1.5, CompareADouble()))->x;

    cout << i << endl;
}
```

A `binary_search` example providing both comparisons with polymorphism:

```
class CompareADouble {
public:
    bool operator () (const double d, A& a) { return d < a.x; }
    bool operator () (A& a, const double d) { return a.x < d; }
};

...

    bool exists = binary_search(v.begin(), v.end(), 1.5, CompareADouble());
    cout << exists << endl; // false

    exists = binary_search(v.begin(), v.end(), 1.0, CompareADouble());
    cout << exists << endl; // true because 1.0 < 1 == false && 1 < 1.0 == false
```

Comment: -1: This does not work.  In this particular example, the `1.5` will simply be converted to `int` as an argument to `lower_bound`.  In a more complex example, it simply won't compile.

Comment: I invite you to compile the more complex example or explain how much more complex it has to be...

Comment: @Ben: Now try that with `upper_bound` or `binary_search`, or with a custom comparator function/functor...

Comment: @Ben: Interesting.  I didn't think that would compile (although I believes it only compiles by exploiting the particular implementation of `lower_bound`, etc.).  Ok, so last issue before I rescind my downvote: `binary_search` with a custom comparator?

Comment: @Oli: I assumed you'd ask so I was already working on it.  Note that the comparison class would be unnecessary if I implemented standalone `operator<(double, A)` and `operator<(A, double`

Comment: @Ben: Then I stand corrected!  I'm about to swap my -1 to a +1.  All these experiments could probably benefit from being rolled into one example, though, for clarity's sake...

Comment: @Ben: Even in the case of, say, `lower_bound`, I think it would be safest to define both permutations of the comparator.  Technically, an STL implementation could choose to compare in either direction.

Comment: @Ben: And in fact, I think for the OP's case, a functor is mandatory, because both types would be primitives, which one cannot declare operator overloads for.

Comment: I've yet to work through your examples, but a quick note: I don't like overloading operator<, even if it works. My particular Base class has several floating-point members and it would be ambiguous without a function name which fields are compared with operator<(double,Base). I'd much rather use a functor that I can name "BaseTimeComparator".

Comment: @Ben: You're right about my misunderstanding and the solution - I for some reason assumed the algorithm makes comparisons between container members which is, of course, nonsense. 

Thanks for your help and discussion, Oli and Ben.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a null pointer, and design your comparison function ignore it, and only test the other object for a specific attribute.

Comment: +1: Grim!  But I suppose it would work.  The functor would have to do check which of its arguments was `NULL` each time, and flip the logic accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could, in a way, by using a static method:

```
class Base {
...
public:
  static Base *newSearchInstance(double t, int d) {return new Base(t,d);};
...
};
```

and in the call to LowerBound:

```
Base* pLow = *(lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),
                         Base::newSearchInstance(3.5,0), //<------
                         BaseTimeComp()));
```

This means you don't have to have knowledge of any of the derived classes, but *getting an instance of Base kind of defeats the purpose of Base being abstract in the first place*. You would just as well make the constructor public.

Comment: Yeah, this really does defeat the purpose.