# How to use std::find/std::find_if with a vector of custom class objects?

Tags: stl, stl-algorithm, c++

I have a class representing a user called `Nick` and I want to use `std::find_if` on it, where I want to find if the userlist vector has an object included with the same username I pass in. I did a few attempts by trying to create a new `Nick` object for the username I want to test and overloading the `== operator` and then trying to use `find/find_if` on the object:

```
    std::vector<Nick> userlist;
    std::string username = "Nicholas";

if (std::find(userlist.begin(), userlist.end(), new Nick(username, false)) != userlist.end())) {
    std::cout << "found";
}
```

I have overloaded the `== operator` so comparing Nick == Nick2 should work, but the function returns `error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'Nick' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`.

Here is my Nick class for reference:

```
class Nick {
private:
    Nick() {
        username = interest = email = "";
                    is_op = false;
    };
public:
    std::string username;
    std::string interest;
    std::string email;
    bool is_op;

    Nick(std::string d_username, std::string d_interest, std::string d_email, bool d_is_op) {
        Nick();
        username = d_username;
        interest = d_interest;
        email = d_email;
        is_op = d_is_op;
    };
    Nick(std::string d_username, bool d_is_op) {
        Nick();
        username = d_username;
        is_op = d_is_op;
    };
    friend bool operator== (Nick &n1, Nick &n2) {
        return (n1.username == n2.username);
    };
    friend bool operator!= (Nick &n1, Nick &n2) {
        return !(n1 == n2);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to define operator== with two Objects outside your class, as a tool function, not a member.

Then to make it friend just put the declaration of the function inside the class.

try something like this:

```
class Nick {

public:
    friend bool operator== ( const Nick &n1, const Nick &n2);
};


bool operator== ( const Nick &n1, const Nick &n2) 
{
        return n1.username == n2.username;
}
```

Also your find should look like this:

```
std::find(userlist.begin(), userlist.end(), Nick(username, false) );
```

No need of "new".

Comment: Actually, instead of defining a friend function you should just use member function bool operator==(const Nick& a).

Comment: You have the choice but there a lot of programmers who like to avoid member if not needed and to have operator like == as external free friend functions. I think it's also the case of the standard library implementations.

Comment: Just tried as you suggested. Shouldn't the answer look like this: `std::find(userlist.begin(), userlist.end(), &Nick(username, false) );`?

Comment: @Nikko - What is the advantage of an "external free friend function" which can work only on a single class?

Answer (score 51):

If you are using C++0X you can use a simple lambda expression

```
std::string username = "Nicholas";    
std::find_if(userlist.begin(), userlist.end(), [username](Nick const& n){
    return n.username == username;
})
```

Comment: @Nikko he also doesn't say that he isn't. Thus the word "if" at the beginning of this answer.

Comment: Yes this all made some kind of sense in 2011 and maybe there was an edit after my comment...

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @mkaes, i already had some understanding of using lambda functions this way but just needed to clarify it, IMHO i think this should have been the accepted answer as it does not require overloading a operator, which should only be done when necessary as it will cause a messy API if used excessively, so thanks a ton for your answer, helped alot. (=

Answer (score 10):

I know that you wanted to overload the `==` operator, but the same thing can easily be done with a predicate:

```
struct UsernameIs {
    UsernameIs( string s ) : toFind(s) { }
    bool operator() (const Nick &n)
        { return n.username == toFind; }
    string toFind;
};

int main()
{
    vector<Nick> vn(10);
    string nameToFind = "something";
    find_if(vn.begin(), vn.end(), UsernameIs(nameToFind));
}
```

Note that in C++0x, you can do the same thing with a lambda expression much more concisely.

Comment: I am getting `error : no match for function UsernameIs` . What could be the issue ?

Answer (score 3):

You are passing a pointer to the find function.  Drop the new:

```
std::find(userlist.begin(), userlist.end(), Nick(username, false))
```

Also, your operators should accept their arguments by const reference, they don't modify them.

```
bool operator== (const Nick &n1, const Nick &n2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am noticing you are trying to call one constructor from another in this manner:

```
Nick(std::string d_username, bool d_is_op) {
        Nick();
 ...
```

Well, sorry, but this doesn't work. The line `Nick()` just creates a temporary and doesn't affect `this`. Constructor forwarding is only possible in C++0x (the upcoming standard)

As to your problem - this question asked a couple of days ago about binary_search covers the same grounds. The top answer is just awesome.

[Mystical restriction on std::binary_search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919405/mystical-restriction-on-stdbinary-search)

HTH.

P.S. Ideally this should have been a comment, but it's just too verbose

Answer (score 0):

You can use boost::bind

```
std::find_if( userlist.begin(), userlist.end(),
            boost::bind( & Nick::isFound,
                         _1 ) );
```

just implement bool Nick::isFound()

You can also pass the criteria

```
std::find_if( userlist.begin(), userlist.end(),
              boost::bind( & Nick::compare,
                           _1,
                           nick ) );
```

implement

```
bool Nick::compare( const Nick & nick )
{
    return this->username == nick.username;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Nick.h

```
#include <string>

class Nick {
private:
    Nick() {
        username = interest = email = "";
        is_op = false;
    };
public:
    std::string username;
    std::string interest;
    std::string email;
    bool is_op;

    Nick(std::string d_username, std::string d_interest, std::string d_email, bool d_is_op) {
        Nick();
        username = d_username;
        interest = d_interest;
        email = d_email;
        is_op = d_is_op;
    };
    Nick(std::string d_username, bool d_is_op) {
        Nick();
        username = d_username;
        is_op = d_is_op;
    };

    bool operator==(const Nick& refNick) const
    {
        if (username != refNick.username)
            return false;
        if (interest != refNick.interest)
            return false;
        if (email != refNick.email)
            return false;
        if (is_op != refNick.is_op)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    bool operator!=(const Nick& refNick) const
    {
        if (username == refNick.username)
            return true;
        if (interest == refNick.interest)
            return true;
        if (email == refNick.email)
            return true;
        if (is_op == refNick.is_op)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Nick.h"

int main()
{
    std::vector<Nick> userlist;
    std::string username = "Nicholas";    
    Nick Nicholas(username, false);
    Nick John("John", true);        
    userlist.push_back(Nicholas);

    std::vector<Nick>::iterator it;

    it = std::find(userlist.begin(), userlist.end(), Nick("Nicholas", false));
    if(it != userlist.end())
        std::cout << "\n" << Nicholas.username << " was found.";
    else
        std::cout << "\n" << Nicholas.username << " was not found.";

    it = std::find(userlist.begin(), userlist.end(), John);
    if (it != userlist.end())
        std::cout << "\n" << John.username << " was found.";
    else
        std::cout << "\n" << John.username << " was not found.";
}
```

Result

```
Nicholas was found.
John was not found.
```