# c++ using find_if with vector objects

Tags: c++

I have a vector(details) containing class objects, i am trying to use find_if to look for a record in the vector. I searched through some solutions on it on stackoverflow and tried out the solutions.

e.g [How to use std::find/std::find_if with a vector of custom class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939129/how-to-use-stdfind-stdfind-if-with-a-vector-of-custom-class-objects)

but on the line of find_if it gives me error

```
expected primary-expression before "[" token
expected primary-expression before "const"
```

---

```
    std::vector<user> details;
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Please enter a name\n";
    std::cin >> name;

    std::find_if(details.begin(), details.end(),
                   [&name](user const& userInfo)
                   {return userInfo.getName()==name;});
```

I am using Dev-C++.

Comment: You need C++11 support for this.

Comment: What compiler do you use with Dev-C++ ?

Comment: @Raxvan definitely not c++11. is there any way to write it in non c++11 way?

Comment: See @Schnommus' answer in the question you linked.

Comment: @user3493435 it dependent on the compiler, if you have a newwer one you can add a switch in dev c to enable c++11 features. That's why i was asking for the compiler and it's version.

Comment: @Raxvan There are newer builds of Dev-C++, but from what I've seen on this site, everyone is using Dev-C++ packaged with outdated versions of mingw.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use std::find/std::find\_if with a vector of custom class objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939129/how-to-use-stdfind-stdfind-if-with-a-vector-of-custom-class-objects)