# C2678 when compiling. Visual Studio refers to xutility

Tags: c++

Basically, I probably did something wrong. And Visual Studio is yelling at me and I am like a deaf person who is just sitting there while being yelled at and thinking: "What do you want from me?". Anyways I have narrowed it down to a single if statement:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < countries.size(); i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < countries.size(); x++) {
            if (countries[i].thoughtsof[x] < -50) {
                for (int v = 0; v < currentwars.size(); v++) {
                    if ( (std::find(currentwars[v].Agressors.begin(), currentwars[v].Agressors.end(), countries[i]) != currentwars[v].Agressors.end() || std::find(currentwars[v].Defenders.begin(), currentwars[v].Defenders.end(), countries[i]) != currentwars[v].Defenders.end()) && (std::find(currentwars[v].Agressors.begin(), currentwars[v].Agressors.end(), countries[x]) != currentwars[v].Agressors.end() || std::find(currentwars[v].Defenders.begin(), currentwars[v].Defenders.end(), countries[x]) != currentwars[v].Defenders.end()) ) {
                        result = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        result = false;
                    }
                    if (!result) {
                        War war(countries[i], countries[x]);
                        currentwars.push_back(war);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The error is basically saying: "binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'Country' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

Double clicking on it refers me to this block:

```
template<class _InIt,
class _Ty> inline
_InIt _Find_unchecked1(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, const _Ty& _Val, false_type)
{   // find first matching _Val
for (; _First != _Last; ++_First)
    if (*_First == _Val)
        break;
return (_First);
}
```

But, in War class header I have set both vectors as Country ones:

```
std::vector<Country> Agressors;
std::vector<Country> Defenders;
```

Excuse me if I formated something not too good. It is just that I am slowly going into insanity as I am trying to fix this for 2 days. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6939129/3670437). And it would be better if you had separated the if statement into smaller bool variables.