# find objects that have the same value for an attribute in a vector of objects

Tags: c++, vector

I have a random object as follows

```
struct myObject
{
    int numberOfSymbols;
    std::vector<int> symbolNumbers;
    std::vector<int> Pins;
    std::vector<std::string> pinNumList;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> pinNumNameMap;

}

std::vector<myObject> m_myObject;
```

And a function loads up this myObject vector with information. I need to do some sanity checking on that populated data as follows:

See what all objects have the same number of `Pins`and `pinNumNameMap`and then do an action based on the result of that comparison.

I am not sure on how to group/find the objects that have the same number of pins because, sometimes this vector can grow as long as 50-100 objects. I am new to C++ coming from C#. In C# we use lambda expressoins/iterators etc to do this..not sure how do we do it in C++

Comment: do u have a quick short example to show me your idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to define a custom `operator==` to loop over `Pins` and pinNumNameMap (incidentally, I just answered another question about comparing custom objects in a vector [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46942657/find-iterator-in-a-stdvector/46943104#46943104)).

Here is what I came up with, although it might not be exactly what you need depending on whether you need all the entries in `Pins` and `pinNumNameMap` to match exactly or if comparing the size of the containers is enough.

EDIT: I merged the two sections into one to illustrate the possible use.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <functional>

struct myObject
{
    int numberOfSymbols;
    std::list<int> symbolNumbers;
    std::list<int> Pins;
    std::list<std::string> pinNumList;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> pinNumNameMap;

    friend bool operator == (const myObject& _this, const myObject& _other)
    {
        // Check if entry sizes match
        if (_this.Pins.size() != _other.Pins.size() ||
            _this.pinNumNameMap.size() != _this.pinNumNameMap.size())
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Now check if the things inside the entries also match
        bool same(true);
        for (auto this_it = _this.Pins.begin(), other_it = _other.Pins.begin(); this_it != _this.Pins.end(); ++this_it, ++other_it)
        {
            same &= (*this_it == *other_it);
        }

        for (const auto& name : _this.pinNumNameMap)
        {
            same &= (_other.pinNumNameMap.find(name.first) != _other.pinNumNameMap.end() &&
                    _other.pinNumNameMap.at(name.first) == name.second);
        }
        return same;
    }

};

// std::reference_wrapper is used when you want to
// store references to objects in a container like
// std::vector (you can't store myObject&)
typedef std::reference_wrapper<myObject> ObjRef;

int main()
{

    std::vector<myObject> m_myObject;

    // This is your comparison object.
    // Use this to identify objectsin the original
    // container with matching Pins and pinNumNameMaps.
    myObject tmp;
    tmp.Pins = {1, 2, 3};
    tmp.pinNumNameMap =
    {
        {"pin 1", "name 1"},
        {"pin 2", "name 2"},
        {"pin 3", "name 3"}
    };

    std::vector<ObjRef> objectsWithCertainPins;

    for (auto& obj : m_myObject)
    {
        if (obj == tmp)
        {
            // Use std::reference_wrapper to avoid
            // copying large myObject instances
            objectsWithCertainPins.emplace_back(std::ref(obj));
        }
    }

    // Now you can iterate over objects in your
    // objectsWithCertainPins container.
    for (auto& obj : objectsWithCertainPins)
    {
        std::cout << "Pins:";
        for (const auto& p : obj.get().Pins)
        {
            std::cout << " " << p;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok.what if we want to compare each object in vector with all other objects and find those that have the same `pins` and `pinnumnamemap`